# How to join(merge) multiple data frames and keep column names in R

Tags: r, join, dplyr, merge

I have four data frames:

```r
df01 <- data.frame(ID = c("001","002","003","004"),
                      Name = c("Ben","Jennifer","Mark","Brad"),
                      LastName = c("Affleck","Lopez","Anthony","Pitt"))
df02 <- data.frame(ID = c("001","002"),
                      Age = c(37,41))
df03 <- data.frame(ID = c("003"),
                      Age = c(28))
df04 <- data.frame(ID = c("004"),
                      Age = c(48))
```

I am trying to join using dplyr package with the function left_join like this:

```r
df <- df01 %>% 
  left_join(df02, by = "ID") %>% 
  left_join(df03, by = "ID") %>% 
  left_join(df04, by = "ID")
```

And my current outcome is

```r
> df
   ID     Name LastName Age.x Age.y Age
1 001      Ben  Affleck    37    NA  NA
2 002 Jennifer    Lopez    41    NA  NA
3 003     Mark  Anthony    NA    28  NA
4 004     Brad     Pitt    NA    NA  48
```

But my expected outcome would be:

```r
> df
   ID     Name LastName Age
1 001      Ben  Affleck  37
2 002 Jennifer    Lopez  41
3 003     Mark  Anthony  28
4 004     Brad     Pitt  48
```

I would like to say, this is a very simplified issue because one solution would be binding rows and next applying left_join like this

```r
dfx <- bind_rows(df02,df03,df04)

df <- df01 %>% 
  left_join(dfx, by = "ID")
```

but the real issue includes larger-than-memory and applying that solution would do an error called "Error: cannot allocate vector of size ..."

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a use of `Reduce` (or you can use `purrr::reduce`, effectively the same thing):

```r
fun <- function(a, b) {
  out <- left_join(a, b, by = "ID", suffix = c("", ".y"))
  if (all(c("Age", "Age.y") %in% names(out))) {
    out <- mutate(out, Age = coalesce(Age.y, Age)) %>%
      select(-Age.y)
  }
  out
}
Reduce(fun, list(df01, df02, df03, df04))
#    ID     Name LastName Age
# 1 001      Ben  Affleck  37
# 2 002 Jennifer    Lopez  41
# 3 003     Mark  Anthony  28
# 4 004     Brad     Pitt  48
```

Quick walk-through:

- `Reduce` calls the function (`fun` here) on the first two elements of the list provided; it then calls with that return value and the 3rd element in the list; then calls with *that* return value and the 4th; until the list is exhausted
- `coalesce` is a great function that returns the first non-`NA` value of the values provided; and it's vectorized, which is great; try `coalesce(c(1,NA,3), c(22,33,44))` and get `c(1,33,3)`.

Answer (score 0):

As you have only one value for each new `Age` column. You could sum all of them after the left joins.

```
df <- df01 %>% 
  left_join(df02, by = "ID") %>% 
  left_join(df03, by = "ID") %>% 
  left_join(df04, by = "ID") %>% 
  mutate(Age = sum(c_across(stringr::str_subset(colnames(.), "Age")), na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  select(-stringr::str_subset(colnames(.), "Age."))
```

With `stringr` package you can select all columns that have "Age" in their name. Then you could do the same to remove all columns with "Age."

Answer (score 0):

Generally, join operations are used to combine tables with different column sets. Here df02, df03 and df04 have all the same columns and seem to require row binding, rather than joining.
I would do like this:

```
> bind_rows(df02, df03, df04) %>% left_join(df01, ., by = "ID")
   ID     Name LastName Age
1 001      Ben  Affleck  37
2 002 Jennifer    Lopez  41
3 003     Mark  Anthony  28
4 004     Brad     Pitt  48
```

In case you are not sure that the IDs in those tables are unique, you need to decide what to do with duplicates. `%>% group_by(ID) %>% summarize(Age = first(Age))` before the left join would select the first age among duplicate IDs, if any.